# Legal precaution to work as freelance pentester

Tags: penetration-test, legal, career

I got some extra work as a freelance pentester.
I was contacted by a security company to help them pentest one of their client website.
What are the standard legal precaution that I have to take so that I’m covered in case of problem?
Is there any legal paper that they have to sign and and send to me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends very much on jurisdiction - there isn't a single global answer.

Comment: This is a question for that security company.